# Accidentally changed the attributes of all the files and folders of a user to Read-only

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-permissions, read-only, control-panel

Story behind: I wanted to upload a file located in a hidden folder(by default). The file explorer that prompted by the file uploading site did not have the "Hidden items" checkbox in the View tab(didn't have the tab panel at all). I right clicked and clicked properties, thought by changing the attributes to hidden would display the hidden files(I don't know what was going on in my mind). It showed up a progress bar with 6 something minutes remaining, got to know that something was up. Cancelled it. Wanted to revert what I just had done, did the Read-only and let it complete. Later found out that it had un-hided all the hidden files and folders too. I gave all the administration permissions.

It's only been done to C:\Users\USER1
(I don't have/want to revert back using a system restore)

I want to revert all this, and want the default setup. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no practical way to restore permissions across a user profile folder. The permissions are not the same across all the folders and files, and the permissions for your specific computer will vary widely based on the applications you have installed, how you have them configured, and other factors.

The correct thing to do in this situation is to create an entirely new user account and login with it to create new profile folders, then move the necessary files from the messed up profile to the new profile.

Once you're sure everything necessary has been moved across and you have a good backup of the old stuff, delete the old profile folders and user account.

Comment: I see, so tl;dr nothing can be done about it. I don't want the hassle of making another user and copy paste everything, which will eventually break things further. So my question is that, is it safe if I leave the things as they are now, keeping in mind that I don't mess with things I don't know(at least not intentionally)?

Comment: I would say no, it's not safe. Safety in the age of connections and the internet and malicious actors has a lot of considerations. Permissions on the folder in your user profile are a key part of the multi-layered security your computer uses to protect you from malware. So, if you will only use this computer offline, air-gapped from any internet connection, as a static console, you'll probably be mostly OK. But, if you intend to use it as most people use their computers, no, it's not OK.

Comment: But its _JUST_ NOT hidden, not like I made it write accessible. Its still read-only, just not hidden.

Comment: Being read-only is probably safer, yes, but also means you're not likely to be able to use it very well. But it comes down to this: Your profile is broken. You WILL experience problems due to this brokenness, and the only viable way to repair this brokenness is to create a new profile.